# How to perform search in a FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

## Description

My Firebase NoSQL Database should look somewhat like this:

[image: Users]

A user Java model should get pushed whenever a new user signs in.

## Problem

How to check if the user with the email address already has an account? Since the email address is at: Root > PushID > email; and push ID is automatically generated, I am not sure on how to iterate on all push ID's and check if any of them has its email key set to the specified value.

I have read the documentation but unable to figure out how to solve this problem.

#### Learning from Shubhank's answer

*Firebase Methods which involve a child can be applied to any of its children irrespective of its level in the hierarchy i.e. not limited to immediate children.*

In this problem, the child to be searched was 2 levels below the common parent. The first level child can be ignored and query methods can be directly applied on the target child.

Comment: Maybe you use FireBase's auth system? It handles all stuff for you.

Comment: That approach will be okay for this particular problem, but I want to know if this was for something other than users signing in, how would that be solved? That is, in general how one performs search-like operation in a FirebaseDatabase.

Further, I want to store additional details belonging to a user which are not stored in the authentication system and thus I need to have each user as a child in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first make a model class for the user

```
class User { 
    public String email;
    public String name;
}
```

Then get the users from the db and map them into User objects

1. **Simple loop through all results query**

   ```
   FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

   // i don't know the end point since you have not specified it in the image           
   database.getReference("myUsersEndPoint").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
               new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                         User user = data.getValue(User.class);
                         if (myField.getText().toString().eqaulsIgnoreCase(user.email)) {
                           // exist
                         }
                     }

                  }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
                   Log.w("MyApp", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
         }
      });
   ```
2. **Searching only for specific Values**
     In this example, we use the `orderByChild` and `equalTo` method to limit result to specific child value

   ```
   FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

   // i don't know the end point since you have not specified it in the image           
   database.getReference("myUsersEndPoint").orderByChild("email").equalTo("emailToSearchhere").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
               new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                         // here the user will have the specified email only 
                     }

                  }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
                   Log.w("MyApp", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
         }
      });
   ```

Comment: Is there any other way? Like performing a query rather than getting all the children and iterating over them in the Java code to find the match.

Comment: you can actually use orderBy and limit results to 10 values only so that the query is performed server side. i will try to make up a example in a while. You can read it here till then https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: So, using orderByChild on a DatabaseReference we can order the result set based on any child independent of its location in the hierarchy? In this case it was two levels below the users end point, with push ID in between.

Comment: haven't tested it with this much nesting but you should definitely avoid that as it will slow the query since there will be lot more data to be matched creating performance issue.